# Can we use YouTube Analytics Api using Java and Eclipse?

Tags: java, youtube-api

```
I tried reading google tutorials and doing the YouTube Analytics Api example. But, I am    unable to make the code.  Can someone help me to make it (using Java and Eclipse) ?
```

it shows an error  in Import file

```
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Channel;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ChannelListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtubeAnalytics.YoutubeAnalytics;
import com.google.api.services.youtubeAnalytics.model.ResultTable;
import com.google.api.services.youtubeAnalytics.model.ResultTable.ColumnHeaders;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
```

Example :

package com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.youtube_analytics_cmdline_report_sample;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.FileCredentialStore;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Channel;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ChannelListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtubeAnalytics.YoutubeAnalytics;
import com.google.api.services.youtubeAnalytics.model.ResultTable;
import com.google.api.services.youtubeAnalytics.model.ResultTable.ColumnHeaders;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
```

public class Samp {

```
/**
 * Demo displaying YouTube metrics from a user's channel using the YouTube Data and YouTube
 * Analytics APIs.  It also uses OAuth2 for authorization.
 *
 * @author Christoph Schwab-Ganser and Jeremy Walker
 */
public class YouTubeAnalyticsReports {

  /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
  private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  /** Global instance of Youtube object to make general YouTube API requests. */
  private static YouTube youtube;

  /** Global instance of YoutubeAnalytics object to make analytic API requests. */
  private static YoutubeAnalytics analytics;

  /**
   * Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected YouTube data.
   *
   * @param scopes list of scopes needed to access general and analytic YouTube info.
   */
  private static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes) throws Exception {

    // Load client secrets.
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(
            JSON_FACTORY,
            YouTubeAnalyticsReports.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));

    // Checks that the defaults have been replaced (Default = "Enter X here").
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
        || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
      System.err.println(
          "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=youtube"
          + "into youtube-analytics-cmdline-report-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // Set up file credential store.
    FileCredentialStore credentialStore =
        new FileCredentialStore(
            new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
                     ".credentials/youtube-analytics-api-report.json"),
                     JSON_FACTORY);

    // Set up authorization code flow.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = 
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                                                JSON_FACTORY,
                                                clientSecrets,
                                                scopes)
      .setCredentialStore(credentialStore).build();

    // Authorize.
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }

  /**
   * Authorizes user, gets user's default channel via YouTube Data API, and gets/prints stats on
   * user's channel using the YouTube Analytics API.
   *
   * @param args command line args (not used).
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Scopes required to access YouTube general and analytics information.
    List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
        );

    try {
      Credential credential = authorize(scopes);

      // YouTube object used to make all non-analytic API requests.
      youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName("youtube-analytics-api-report-example")
        .build();

      // YouTube object used to make all analytic API requests.
      analytics = new YoutubeAnalytics.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName("youtube-analytics-api-report-example")
        .build();

      // Constructs request to get channel id for current user.
      YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youtube.channels().list("id,snippet");
      channelRequest.setMine(true);
      channelRequest.setFields("items(id,snippet/title)");
      ChannelListResponse channels = channelRequest.execute();

      // List of channels associated with user.
      List<Channel> listOfChannels = channels.getItems();

      // Grab default channel which is always the first item in the list.
      Channel defaultChannel = listOfChannels.get(0);
      String channelId = defaultChannel.getId();

      PrintStream writer = System.out;
      if (channelId == null) {
        writer.println("No channel found.");
      } else {
        writer.println("Default Channel: " + defaultChannel.getSnippet().getTitle() +
            " ( " + channelId + " )\n");

        printData(writer, "Views Over Time.", executeViewsOverTimeQuery(analytics, channelId));
        printData(writer, "Top Videos", executeTopVideosQuery(analytics, channelId));
        printData(writer, "Demographics", executeDemographicsQuery(analytics, channelId));
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the views and unique viewers per day.
   *
   * @param analytics the analytics service object used to access the API.
   * @param id the string id from which to retrieve data.
   * @return the response from the API.
   * @throws IOException if an API error occurred.
   */
  private static ResultTable executeViewsOverTimeQuery(YoutubeAnalytics analytics,
      String id) throws IOException {

    return analytics.reports()
        .query("channel==" + id,     // channel id
               "2012-01-01",         // Start date.
               "2012-01-14",         // End date.
               "views,uniques")      // Metrics.
        .setDimensions("day")
        .setSort("day")
        .execute();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the top video by views.
   *
   * @param analytics the analytics service object used to access the API.
   * @param id the string id from which to retrieve data.
   * @return the response from the API.
   * @throws IOException if an API error occurred.
   */
  private static ResultTable executeTopVideosQuery(YoutubeAnalytics analytics,
      String id) throws IOException {

    return analytics.reports()
        .query("channel==" + id,                          // channel id
               "2012-01-01",                              // Start date.
               "2012-08-14",                              // End date.
               "views,subscribersGained,subscribersLost") // Metrics.
        .setDimensions("video")
        .setSort("-views")
        .setMaxResults(10)
        .execute();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the demographics report
   *
   * @param analytics the analytics service object used to access the API.
   * @param id the string id from which to retrieve data.
   * @return the response from the API.
   * @throws IOException if an API error occurred.
   */
  private static ResultTable executeDemographicsQuery(YoutubeAnalytics analytics,
      String id) throws IOException {
    return analytics.reports()
        .query("channel==" + id,     // channel id
               "2007-01-01",         // Start date.
               "2012-08-14",         // End date.
               "viewerPercentage")   // Metrics.
        .setDimensions("ageGroup,gender")
        .setSort("-viewerPercentage")
        .execute();
  }

  /**
   * Prints the output from the API. The channel name is printed along with
   * each column name and all the data in the rows.
   * @param writer stream to output to
   * @param title title of the report
   * @param results data returned from the API.
   */
  private static void printData(PrintStream writer, String title, ResultTable results) {
    writer.println("Report: " + title);
    if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
      writer.println("No results Found.");
    } else {

      // Print column headers.
      for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) {
        writer.printf("%30s", header.getName());
      }
      writer.println();

      // Print actual data.
      for (List<Object> row : results.getRows()) {
        for (int colNum = 0; colNum < results.getColumnHeaders().size(); colNum++) {
          ColumnHeaders header = results.getColumnHeaders().get(colNum);
          Object column = row.get(colNum);
          if ("INTEGER".equals(header.getUnknownKeys().get("dataType"))) {
            long l = ((BigDecimal) column).longValue();
            writer.printf("%30d", l);
          } else if ("FLOAT".equals(header.getUnknownKeys().get("dataType"))) {
            writer.printf("%30f", column);
          }  else if ("STRING".equals(header.getUnknownKeys().get("dataType"))) {
            writer.printf("%30s", column);
          } else {
            // default output.
            writer.printf("%30s", column);
          }
        }
        writer.println();
      }
      writer.println();
    }
  }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could state what error do you see in Imports?

But assuming you are finding errors in Imports it means you are missing project dependencies in your project path. Find the dependencies in Maven POM.xml. If you are not using Maven to build your project, then please download all the dependent JAR files as mentioned in POM.xml

Comment: Why go for Maven ?  why we can't use ant? could you Please reply?

Comment: Checkout this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20756425/3673638

Recently I have started using Gradle instead of Maven
http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/why-build-your-java-projects-with-gradle/240168608