# Using Maven with Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have a question.
I just got a new job as tester and they do not have automation, it is all manual testing. They want me to build a framework to automate test cases. Application is build with *Ant* and I have never used it.
I only used *Maven* so far.

Is it possible to build an automation framework with *Maven* to run test cases of an application that is build by *Ant*?

Comment: What is the result of the ant build, a jar, a war another binaries file?

Comment: I have not seen the application yet, so I have no idea. My last framework that I built was cucumber with Maven and Junit. Can I build the same framework by using ant instead of maven? or if I build it with maven again, will be able to run my test cases?

Comment: For this requirement, any of Ant, Maven, Gradle will work and more or less with the same ease. Each of these tools has some pros and cons. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755437/java-build-tools-ant-vs-maven/20756425) for a quick comparison. It's like writing the application logic either using Java, Python, .Net - use whichever you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Maven for this, since Ant has built-in tasks for running JUnit tests:

- [JUnit](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) (3 & 4)
- [JUnitLauncher](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitlauncher.html) (JUnit 5).

So now grab your reading glasses and start learning Ant: [**Ant Manual**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/)

---

*FYI:* When joining an existing project, it is generally better to stick with the technologies already used by the project, rather than complicating the project with new technologies. This is especially true when the new technology doesn't really add any functionality, that isn't already supported by the existing technology.